# adverse effects of reduced food variety on microbiome

Tags: brain, gut-bacteria

We often see, in science fiction, food being produced from, say, algae or yeast. Any idea what could be the effect of such a limited diet on the gut microbiome? Could there be any side-effect that would have an influence on the brain?

I know that gut microbiome has been tentatively linked to the autism spectrum in some cases, and that heavily processed food may affect it (don't worry, I don't equate "natural" with "good for you"). I'm thinking that food designed only with the needs of human metabolism in mind might ignore the needs of gut bacteria.

I understand this is very speculative, I'm just hoping someone would know of any research in that field.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site!  Unfortunately, this question is way too broad to be answerable in a specific way... You would have to narrow it down to a very specific diet, and ask about a specific issue that that diet could cause in order for us to be able even to adress the issue.  And even at that, I have a feeling that there will be a lot less solid answers than simple speculation, since science fiction is generally not the realm studied by scientists.  :)  Anyhow, please [edit] to make your question more specific.  Thanks!

Comment: In addition to following the guidance from @rotaredom, I encourage you to take the time to take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I interpret your question as essentially asking this:

*What is the effect of a limited diet on the gut microbiome? Can a limited diet affect the brain via the microbiome?*

To simplify the answer, let's make some assumptions --

1. This "limited" diet is nutritionally complete, meaning that it contains all the macro- and and micro-nutrients needed for human metabolism.  This includes all nutrients that we normally receive via microbiota, such as [vitamin K<sub>2</sub>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitamin_K#Absorption_and_dietary_need). Said another way, this diet only affects host health via the microbiome, and there are no effects of malnutrition that would confound our inferences.
2. There is no flow of genes between organisms in the gut microbiome or introduction of new organisms from outside sources, *i.e.* only the organisms that are present at the start of the dietary change will be present throughout.  Thus, all observed changes are directly attributable to changes in species abundance.  In reality, there is extensive horizontal gene transfer in the gut microbiome, with new genes obtained from [endogenous](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6142633/) and [exogenous](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20376150) sources.
3. Following the logic of point 2, there is no mutation.  The microbes present at the end of this diet are clones of the microbes present at the beginning.  Likewise, [competitive exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Competitive_exclusion_principle) does not lead to the disappearance of low-fitness microbes in the microbiome, just a reduction in their relative abundances.
4. The human host of this microbiome is healthy and not undergoing the physiological changes associated with aging during adherence to this limited diet.

In this simple system, the only things that will change are (1) the total number of microbes and (2) the relative abundances of microbial strains.  Different microbes contain different genes for metabolizing different food sources.  For example, if this simple diet contains carbohydrate *A* that is metabolized exclusively by the enzyme encoded by gene *α*, then microbes that both contain and express gene *α* will grow in abundance.  Some different microbes may then be able to use the products of the metabolism of carbohydrate *A*, and those microbes may also grow in abundance.  The metabolic interaction network of the human gut microbiome is [extremely complex](https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms15393), as it includes both microbe-microbe and host-microbe metabolite cycling.  Eventually, with the same limited dietary input, the microbiome will reach an equilibrium state where the abundance of each microbe is essentially fixed.  The microbes that are best able to utilize the nutrients provided by the food will maintain a high abundance and can be said to be "very fit" in this particular niche.

Keep in mind that this system is *extremely* simplified, and that microbial fitness in a particular context depends on gene copy number, expression level, enzyme efficiency, [microbe-microbe antagonism](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5464660/), and a menagerie of other factors, notwithstanding regulatory signals from human epithelial cells.

Even if we had two people eating the exact same diet with the exact same initial composition of their microbiomes, human genetics plays a role in the carbohydrates available to commensal microbes, as can been seen with [salivary amylase copy number](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/30974084).

...

Considering the "brain" part of your question, I suggest you Google "[Gut Brain Axis](https://www.google.com/search?q=gut%20brain%20axis)".  [Here's](https://www.nature.com/articles/d42859-019-00021-3) a good summary article with references at the end.